# I cannot show that how they are mutually independent.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Let A1, A2, A3 be (mutually) independent events. Show that 1′ , ′2 and ′3 are also (mutually) independent events, where 1′ , ′2, ′3 are complements of A1, A2 , A3, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with the following

**Lemma.** If the events $A$ and $B$ are independent then  $A$ and $B'$ are independent as well.

*Proof.* Since the union $A=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B')$ is disjoint we have
$$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B')\ ,$$
and this implies
$$P(A\cap B')=P(A)-P(A)\>P(B)=P(A)\bigl(1-P(B)\bigr)=P(A)\>P(B')\qquad\square$$
Turning to your problem, the lemma allows to  infer from the assumption first that $A_1$ and $A_2'$ are independent, and then that $A_1'$ and $A_2'$ are independent.

There remains the case of "all three": By assumption 
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)=P(A_1)\>P(A_2)\>P(A_3)=P(A_1\cap A_2)\>P(A_3)\ .$$
This shows that $A_1\cap A_2$ is independent from $A_3$. The lemma then says that $A_1\cap A_2$ is also independent from $A_3'$, so that we obtain
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3')=P(A_1)\>P(A_2)\>P(A_3')\ .$$
Proceeding in this way we finally obtain
$$P(A_1'\cap A_2'\cap A_3')=P(A_1')\>P(A_2')\>P(A_3')\ .$$

Comment: I get the point thank you!